# Stream android camera over RTMP

Tags: android, camera, h.264, rtmp, mediarecorder

I was searching in all stackoverflow posts , but not find ask for this question.
I need stream video from android camera to rtmp server. In this time, I make rtmp packet, put in rtmp body buffer from pipe:

```
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pipe[1].getFileDescriptor());
```

Settings for media:

```
camera = Camera.open();
mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(0);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(8);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264); 
mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder.getSurface());
```

Then reading data from inputStream into array and put this data to rtmpbody
I`m understand, thats wrong, but I have no idea how make raw h264 streamable

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you already did, if not, you should take a look to these questions.

[Accessing the output video while recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827444/accessing-the-output-video-while-recording)

[Transfer InputStream to another Service (across process boundaries) with ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe() failes with "EBADF (Bad file number)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212152/transfer-inputstream-to-another-service-across-process-boundaries-with-parcelf)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a small project that shows how to put raw h264 into an RTMP format [here](https://github.com/mondain/h264app); its not perfect, but it mostly works.